# Why does Scala not have a return/unit function defined for each monad (in contrast to Haskell)?

Tags: scala, haskell, monads

What is the reason behind the design decision in Scala that monads do not have a return/unit function in contrast to Haskell where each monad has a return function that puts a value into a standard monadic context for the given monad?

For example why List, Option, Set etc... do not have a return/unit functions defined in the standard library as shown in the slides below?

I am asking this because in the reactive Coursera course Martin Odersky explicitly mentioned this fact, as can be seen below in the slides, but did not explain why Scala does not have them even though unit/return is an essential property of a monad.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it seems to me that there is a `unit` for each example of a monad - it's just not in the *trait* itself - why this is so in scala I cannot tell (as I have little to no knowledge of it)

Comment: I'm mainly just a Haskeller, but I thought it was because Scala unlike Haskell does not support dispatching on the *return* type of a function. Note that the monad shows up nowhere in the type of the *argument* to unit.

Comment: Ørjan could you please explain what you mean by dispatch on the return type?

Comment: Haskell has "full" type inference, which means that the types used for a polymorphic/overloaded function can depend not just on the types of the arguments it is passed, but also on what types are expected by the functions that are using its *result*.  This means that Haskell can implement its variant of `unit` (misfortunately called `return`) such that it returns a value of the right monad type for how it is *used* in context.

Comment: What if `unit` would be defined inside the trait itself just as `flatMap`? Would that help on this problem (i.e. no dispatch on result type in Scala) ?

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense to put a `unit` method on monad instances. You'd put it on the companion object. More realistically, if Scala wanted to be like Haskell, it could have had a monad type class, which is [scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad.html)'s approach (where I guess `unit` is called `point`). You have to keep in mind, though, that Odersky's goal (for better or worse) is *not* to reproduce Haskell.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I disagree with "It wouldn't really make sense to ..." but would agree with "It would be difficult in scala to..."

Comment: @ChrisMartin: "You'd put it on the companion object." and people do, but it's usually called `apply`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As Ørjan Johansen said, Scala does not support method dispatching on return type. Scala object system is built over JVM one, and JVM `invokevirtual` instruction, which is the main tool for dynamic polymorphism, dispatches the call based on type of `this` object.

As a side note, dispatching is a process of selecting concrete method to call. In Scala/Java all methods are virtual, that is, the actual method which is called depends on actual type of the object.

```scala
class A { def hello() = println("hello method in A") }

class B extends A { override def hello() = println("hello method in B") }

val x: A = new A
x.hello()  // prints "hello method in A"

val y: A = new B
y.hello()  // prints "hello method in B"
```

Here, even if `y` variable is of type `A`, `hello` method from `B` is called, because JVM "sees" that the actual type of the object in `y` is `B` and invokes appropriate method.

However, JVM only takes the type of the variable on which the method is called into account. It is impossible, for example, to call different methods based on runtime type of arguments without explicit checks. For example:

```scala
class A {
  def hello(x: Number) = println(s"Number: $x")
  def hello(y: Int) = println(s"Integer: $y")
}

val a = new A
val n: Number = 10: Int
a.hello(n)  // prints "Number: 10"
```

Here we have two methods with the same name, but with different parameter type. And even if `n`s actual type is `Int`, `hello(Number)` version is called - it is resolved statically based on `n` static variable type (this feature, static resolution based on argument types, is called overloading). Hence, there is no dynamic dispatch on method arguments. Some languages support dispatching on method arguments too, for example, Common Lisp's CLOS or Clojure's multimethods work like that.

Haskell has advanced type system (it is comparable to Scala's and in fact they both originate in [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), but Scala type system supports subtyping which makes type inference much more difficult) which allows global type inference, at least, without certain extensions enabled. Haskell also has a concept of type classes, which is its tool for dynamic polymorphism. Type classes can be loosely thought of as interfaces without inheritance but with dispatch on parameter *and return value* types. For example, this is a valid type class:

```hs
class Read a where
    read :: String -> a

instance Read Integer where
    read s = -- parse a string into an integer

instance Read Double where
    read s = -- parse a string into a double
```

Then, depending on the context where method is called, `read` function for `Integer` or `Double` can be called:

```hs
x :: Integer
x = read "12345"  // read for Integer is called

y :: Double
y = read "12345.0"  // read for Double is called
```

This is a very powerful technique which has no correspondence in bare JVM object system, so Scala object system does not support it too. Also the lack of full-scale type inference would make this feature somewhat cumbersome to use. So, Scala standard library does not have `return`/`unit` method anywhere - it is impossible to express it using regular object system, there is simply no place where such a method could be defined. Consequently, monad concept in Scala is implicit and conventional - everything with appropriate `flatMap` method can be considered a monad, and everything with the right methods can be used in `for` construction. This is much like duck typing.

However, Scala type system together with its implicits mechanism is powerful enough to express full-featured type classes, and, by extension, generic monads in formal way, though due to difficulties in full type inference it may require adding more type annotations than in Haskell.

This is definition of monad type class in Scala:

```scala
trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def unit[A](a: A): M[A]
  def bind[A, B](ma: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

And this is its implementation for `Option`:

```scala
implicit object OptionMonad extends Monad[Option] {
  def unit[A](a: A) = Some(a)
  def bind[A, B](ma: Option[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] =
    ma.flatMap(f)
}
```

Then this can be used in generic way like this:

```scala
// note M[_]: Monad context bound
// this is a port of Haskell's filterM found here:
// http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#filterM
def filterM[M[_]: Monad, A](as: Seq[A])(f: A => M[Boolean]): M[Seq[A]] = {
  val m = implicitly[Monad[M]]
  as match {
    case x +: xs =>
      m.bind(f(x)) { flg =>
        m.bind(filterM(xs)(f)) { ys =>
          m.unit(if (flg) x +: ys else ys)
        }
      }
    case _ => m.unit(Seq.empty[A])
  }
}

// using it

def run(s: Seq[Int]) = {
  import whatever.OptionMonad  // bring type class instance into scope

  // leave all even numbers in the list, but fail if the list contains 13
  filterM[Option, Int](s) { a =>
    if (a == 13) None
    else if (a % 2 == 0) Some(true)
    else Some(false)
  }
}

run(1 to 16)  // returns None
run(16 to 32)  // returns Some(List(16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32))
```

Here `filterM` is written generically, for any instance of `Monad` type class. Because `OptionMonad` implicit object is present at `filterM` call site, it will be passed to `filterM` implicitly, and it will be able to make use of its methods.

You can see from above that type classes allow to emulate dispatching on return type even in Scala. In fact, this is exactly what Haskell does under the covers - both Scala and Haskell are passing a dictionary of methods implementing some type class, though in Scala it is somewhat more explicit because these "dictionaries" are first-class objects there and can be imported on demand or even passed explicitly, so it is not really a proper dispatching as it is not that embedded.

If you need this amount of genericity, you can use [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library which contains a lot of type classes (including monad) and their instances for some common types, including `Option`.

Comment: I feel like this may overstate the impossibility of `unit` in Scala a bit. I use Scalaz's `1.point` all the time. Sure, you need to specify the monad as a type parameter, but that seems a little less extreme than "there is simply no place where such a method could be defined".

Comment: @TravisBrown, in some sense you're right, but these extension methods are not really dispatching on the expected return value; they use implicit conversion to a class with corresponding method returning an applicative whose type depends on the value.

Comment: @TravisBrown, and, of course, they do require type class instance in scope, so there is no way to have the same name for this method without type classes for all types in the standard library. Without type classes they only become another version of `<Type>.apply`, like it is explained in the other answers, so there really is no way to define such generic method without type classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and educational answer Vladimir!

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you're really saying that Scala's monads don't have a unit function - it's rather just that the *name* of the unit function can vary. That's what seems to be shown in the second slide's examples.

As for why that is so, I think it's just because Scala runs on the JVM, and those function have to be implemented as JVM methods - which are uniquely identified by:

- the class they belong to;
- their name;
- their parameters types.
  But they are not identified by their return type. Since the parameter type generally won't differentiate the various unit functions (it's usually just a generic type), you need different names for them.

In practice, they will often be implemented as the `apply(x)` method on the companion object of the monad class. For example, for the class `List`, the unit function is the `apply(x)` method on the object `List`. By convention, `List.apply(x)` can be called as `List(x)` too, which is more common/idiomatic.

So I guess that Scala at least has a naming convention for the unit function, though it doesn't have a unique name for it :

```
// Some monad :
class M[T] {
  def flatMap[U](f: T => M[U]): M[U] = ???
}
// Companion object :
object M {
  def apply(x: T): M[T] = ??? // Unit function
}

// Usage of the unit function :
val x = ???
val m = M(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

Caveat: I'm still learning Haskell and I'm sort of making up this answer as I go.

---

First, what you already know - that Haskell's `do` notation desugars to *bind*:

[Borrowing this example from Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))

```
add mx my = do
  x <- mx
  y <- my
  return (x + y)

add mx my =
  mx >>= (\x ->
    my >>= (\y ->
      return (x + y)))
```

---

Scala's analogue to `do` is the *for-yield* expression. It similarly desugars each step to `flatMap` (its equivalent of bind).

There's a difference, though: The last `<-` in a for-yield desugars to `map`, not to `flatMap`.

```
def add(mx: Option[Int], my: Option[Int]) =
  for {
    x <- mx
    y <- my
  } yield x + y

def add(mx: Option[Int], my: Option[Int]) =
  mx.flatMap(x =>
    my.map(y =>
      x + y))
```

So because you don't have the "flattening" on the last step, the expression value already has the monad type, so there's no need to "re-wrap" it with something comparable to `return`.

Comment: Thanks for the intersting insight. I just added an extra image to the question (in which Martin shows how map can be defined in terms of unit). So I don't really see why your for-desugaring vs do-desugaring argument would explain why Scala has no unit/return. To me it seems that this difference in desugaring is a consequence and not a cause of the fact that Scala has no unit for their monads (it has map instead, but why? ).

Comment: The suggestion I'm making here is that it doesn't have it because it doesn't need it.

Comment: Interesting insight but why depart from the Haskell convention when not needed?

Comment: @jhegedus It seems to explain why Scala isn't *desperate* to have it.  Although now that I see how Scala `for`s work, a different viewpoint is that Scala *does* have an equivalent to how `return` is used in practice in Haskell `do` blocks, namely the `yield` keyword. Haskell just gets away with having it be a normal function instead of a keyword.

Comment: @jhegedus I think it matters because the de-sugaring shows that the _compiler_ doesn't need to know about the unit function to deal with a monad, while Martin's slide shows one of the reasons why the _author_ of the monad should care about the unit function. Since the unit function will be used by humans and not by the compiler, we can name it whatever we want (though at least respecting a reasonable naming convention will help humans too).

Comment: Think about where this return/unit would be defined. Unlike flatMap/map, it can't be a method of List or Maybe values, because when using return/unit, one doesn't have such a value to start from. This means that if the compiler needs to know where to find an appropriate return/unit, a different mechanism would be needed than just calling a method with the right name, e.g. an implicitly resolved Monad trait.  To avoid introducing such a different mechanism for return/unit, Scala avoids the need for having a common name for it by not using it in the desugaring of for/yield.

Comment: @Ørjan do keep in mind that `yield` isn't quite `return` because it isn't an expression (or a statement, for that matter) - it never exists on its own, only as part of a *for-yield* expression. And, for example, you can't have `for (x <- mx) if (c) yield 1 else yield 2`, and you can't have `val a = yield 1`. The syntax is very rigid: `for (...) yield ...`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I see. It seems structurally equivalent to monad comprehensions, an alternative monad syntax generalizing list comprehensions and which (GHC) Haskell supports as an extension.

Comment: @&#216;rjanJohansen Yeah, that's probably a more accurate assessment. ... on an unrelated note, apparently there's an encoding bug in the SO Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a return function in scala. It is just hard to find.

Scala slightly differs from Haskell in many aspects. Most of that differences are direct consequences of JVM limitations. JVM can not dispatch methods basing on its return type. So Scala introduced type class polymorphism based on implicit evidence to fix this inconvenience.

It is even used in scala standard collections. You may notice numerous usage of `CanBuildFrom` and `CanBuild` implicits used in the scala collection api. See [scala.collection.immutable.List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) for example.

Every time you want to build custom collection you should write realization for this implicits. There are not so many guides for writing one though. I recommend you [this guide](http://daily-scala.blogspot.ru/2010/04/creating-custom-traversable.html). It shows why `CanBuildFrom` is so important for collections and how it is used. In fact that is just another form of the `return` function and anyone familiar with Haskell monads would understand it's importance clearly.

So you may use custom collection as example monads and write other monads basing on provided tutorial.